# TV sci-fi episode - creature stalking a man using a boomerang as a weapon

Tags: story-identification, tv

I watched a lot of TV sci-fi when I was a kid in the late 50's-60's. There was an episode 
where there was a creature stalking a man with a boomerang as a weapon. Towards the end of the show I remember the man hanging from a wooden bridge by his hands and the creature stepping on his hands to make him fall. I would like to know what show and episode. I watch outer limits, twilight zone, one step beyond, and science fiction theater.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like classic [The Outer Limits - Fun and Games.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun_and_Games_%28The_Outer_Limits%29)

> When the male Calco alien, having killed its mate to double its own
>   food supply, confronts Mike on a footbridge over a river of lava,
>   Laura kills the creature with its own saw-bladed boomerang. Mike,
>   hanging by his fingertips and weakened by the ordeal, finally falls
>   off the bridge into the lava.